# How to use X25519 shared secret for encryption?

Tags: c, openssl, x25519

For over a decade I have been using RSA public key for encrypting aes-256-cbc key and iv, before transmission. On the receiving side, the AES key and iv are decrypted using RSA private key.

Now I am about to migrate from openssl 1.1.1 to 3.2.0 version, and I want to use newer encryption methods. Two major changes I am contemplating:

1. Switch from aes-256-cbc to aes-256-gcm for [authenticated encryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption#Authenticated_Encryption_using_GCM_mode).
2. Move away from RSA, towards faster algorithm like X25519.

Unlike RSA public key, X25519 public key cannot be directly used for encrypting the AES key. So I created the shared secret using the X25519 key exchange, as [described here](https://github.com/alexkrontiris/OpenSSL-x25519-key_exchange). I am not sure what to do next. I am not able to find any openssl c/c++ example of how to encrypt using the shared secret. Every encrypt example I can find uses RSA key. What is the **RSA_public_encrypt()** equivalent for encrypting using this shared secret? Can **EVP_PKEY_encrypt()** be used for this?

Comment: Usually the AES key is derived from the shared secret, e.g. with HKDF as in [this example](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x25519/#exchange-algorithm) of the pyca/Cryptography library. You could do it analogously with OpenSSL/C, see [EVP_KDF-HKDF](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.2/man7/EVP_KDF-HKDF.html), *Examples* section.

Comment: I found a way to make it work, and have posted it as an answer. Hopefully, this is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it working after seeing an example in the [openssl site](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_CipherInit_ex.html).

The following code has very little error checking, just to keep it short. The variable **skey** is the shared secret already computed on each side.

On the side of Bob, I encrypted as followed:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *cctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CipherInit_ex2(cctx,EVP_aes_256_cbc(),NULL,NULL,1,NULL) == 1);
std::vector<uint8_t> iv(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_get_iv_length(cctx));
RAND_bytes(&iv.at(0),iv.size());
OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CipherInit_ex2(cctx,NULL,skey,&iv.at(0),1,NULL) == 1);
const char* msg = "This is a secret message, no really!!";
uint8_t output[1000];
int outlen = 0, msg_len = 0;
OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CipherUpdate(cctx,output,&outlen,(uint8_t*)msg,strlen(msg)+1) == 1);
msg_len += outlen;
printf("\noutput size = %d\n",outlen);
OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CipherFinal_ex(cctx,output+outlen,&outlen) == 1);
msg_len += outlen;
printf("\ntotal size = %d\n",msg_len);
int iv_size = iv.size();

std::ofstream os("secret.enc",std::ios_base::binary|std::ios_base::trunc);
os.write((char*)&iv_size,sizeof(iv_size));
os.write((char*)&iv.at(0),iv.size());
os.write((char*)&msg_len,sizeof(msg_len));
os.write((char*)output,msg_len);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(cctx);
```

On the side of Alice, I decrypted as follows:

```
uint8_t input[1000];
char output[1000];
std::ifstream is("secret.enc",std::ios_base::binary);
int iv_size, msg_len,outlen;
is.read((char*)&iv_size,sizeof(iv_size));
std::vector<uint8_t> iv(iv_size);
is.read((char*)&iv.at(0),iv.size());
is.read((char*)&msg_len,sizeof(msg_len));
std::vector<uint8_t> msg(msg_len);
is.read((char*)&msg.at(0),msg.size());
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *cctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CipherInit_ex2(cctx,EVP_aes_256_cbc(),skey,&iv.at(0),0,NULL) == 1);
OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CipherUpdate(cctx,(uint8_t*)output,&outlen,(uint8_t*)&msg.at(0),msg.size()) == 1);
OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CipherFinal_ex(cctx,(uint8_t*)output+outlen,&outlen) == 1);
printf("\nReceived data: %s\n",output);

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(cctx);
```

I was able to print the decrypted message on the receiving side. I could make it work for the aes_256_gcm too.

Based on the feedback from @Topaco, I derived a new key from the shared secret. Then I used this new key to encrypt and decrypt, worked fine. The code for that is follows:

```
EVP_KDF *kdf = EVP_KDF_fetch(NULL, "X963KDF", NULL);
EVP_KDF_CTX *kctx = EVP_KDF_CTX_new(kdf);
EVP_KDF_free(kdf);

OSSL_PARAM params[4], *p = params;
*p++ = OSSL_PARAM_construct_utf8_string(OSSL_KDF_PARAM_DIGEST,(char*)SN_sha256, strlen(SN_sha256));
*p++ = OSSL_PARAM_construct_octet_string(OSSL_KDF_PARAM_SECRET,(char*)skey, skeylen);
*p++ = OSSL_PARAM_construct_octet_string(OSSL_KDF_PARAM_INFO,(char*)"label", (size_t)5);
*p = OSSL_PARAM_construct_end();

uint8_t newKey[30];memset(newKey,0,30);
if(EVP_KDF_derive(kctx, newKey, 30, params) <= 0)
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
EVP_KDF_CTX_free(kctx);
```

Comment: Your approach uses the shared secret itself as the key. The recommended way is not to do this, but to apply a key derivation function to derive the key from the shared secret. This can be found e.g. in [RFC 7748, section 6.1.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7748#section-6.1) and in the [Libsodium documentation](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/advanced/scalar_multiplication#usage).

Comment: Yes, I too prefer not to use the shared secret directly. I need to find the openssl equivalent of creating an aes key from the shared secret.

Comment: I don't believe that OpenSSL offers a function that specifically derives a key from a shared secret. Rather, the intended way is to use a key derivation function (as recommended in the RFC). Which one is not specified and is up to you (e.g. HKDF or X9.63 KDF)). OpenSSL supports various KDFs ([EVP_KDF-HKDF](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.2/man7/EVP_KDF-HKDF.html) or [EVP_KDF-X963](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/EVP_KDF-X963.html)). Pick the implementation of your choice and use it to derive the key from the shared secret.

Comment: @Topaco Your link to KDF-X963 did the trick. I have updated my answer with the improvement. Thanks a lot.